# confluent after reboot OS don't connect to kafka-connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I install kafka with confluent and with this code can run kafka-connect:
`sudo /kafka/bin/connect-distributed.sh /kafka/config/connect-distributed.properties`
then reboot system or stop running command this kafka-connect service is stopped but i want this service is active run always.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an always active service, you can use Systemd, assuming your OS supports it

If you installed Confluent Platform through APT/YUM, you'd have these available

```
sudo systemctl enable confluent-kafka-connect
sudo systemctl start confluent-kafka-connect
```

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/scripted-install.html

Otherwise, you'd have to write the service files yourself

You might want to do the same with the brokers